# Return element text using and condition with different path levels

Tags: xml, xpath

Sample:

```
<ChildElement>
    <Name>Ted</Name>
    <Description>         
        <Details>
            <HairColor>Brown</HairColor>
            <Weight>110</Weight>
            <Height>48</Height>
        </Details>
    </Description>
</ChildElement>
```

I've tried countless variations, but I cannot accomplish the following.

I'm trying to return the value of the `Weight` element (110 in this case), by using an XPath expression that says the `Name` element equals "Ted", and the `Height` element equals "48".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath exprression:

```
ChildElement[Name='Ted' and Description/Details/Height='48']/Description/Details/Weight
```

**Output:**

> 110

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! One additional question, if there's more than one occurance of this, how can I specific which occurance I want to return (e.g. [1] or [2] for the first or second instance of it)

Comment: Disregard my last question, just had to add [1] or [2] in at the end of the query, duh :)        //ChildElement[Name='Ted' and Description/Details/Height='48'][2]/Description/Details/Weight